# array.forEach works, but not when I nest another inside

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach

I've got two pages I'm working on, and both return an array of objects.  When I use the following code, the new results work:

```
this.adminService.waiversGetAll()
    .subscribe((data: Waiver[]) => {
      this.waivers = data;
      this.waivers.forEach((e) => {
        if(e.has_signed === true) {
          e.url = `<a href="${e.signatureUrl}">View</a>`
        } else {
          e.url = `<a href="${e.url}">${e.message}</a>`;
        }
        return e;
      });
      console.log(this.waivers);
    })
  }
```

But when I try to do the same thing with a different array (where I need to update the values of an array nested inside) I don't get updated values:

```
this.adminService.GetUnsignedWaivers()
    .subscribe((data: Player[]) => {
      console.log("data",data);
      data.forEach(e => {
        let record: Object = {};
        for(let i = 0; i < e.waivers.length; i++) {
          console.log(e.waivers[i].has_signed);
          if (e.waivers[i].has_signed === true) {
            e.waivers[i].url = e.waivers[i].signatureUrl;
            console.log(e.waivers[i].url);
            e.waivers[i].message = "View Waiver";
          } else {
            e.waivers[i].url = e.waivers[i].url;
            e.waivers[i].message = e.waivers[i].message;
          }
          console.log(e.waivers[i].message);
          return;
          };
          return e;
      });
      this.size = this.players.length;
      console.log(this.players);
    })
  }
```

When I look at the console.log of e.waivers[i].has_signed, the data is correct, but after that it's not right.

What do I have to do to make this work?  I've tried using a for loop inside the foreach, and a bunch of other stuff.

The data supplied to the loop provides info like:

```
{ 
buyer: "email@someaddress.edu"
event: "COED A"
field: "Main"
net: null
player: {shirtSize: null, avp_id: 12345678, adult: true, …}
team: null
waivers: [{
email: "someemail@gmail.com",
has_signed: true,
message: "Liability Waiver",
signatureUrl: "https://somelink.pdf",
url: "https://somelink.com/somekeyidentifier"
}
```

IF the player has signed the waiver, there will be a signatureUrl field and the message should say "View Waiver" instead of the message telling me what type of waiver they will sign.  I want the url to be set to signatureUrl if they signed, so I can use it in a table that doesn't like manipulation of data.

A visual of what is returned in my table:
[image: You can see the has_signed are displaying as true on some, but the Liability URL is displaying instead of the "View Waiver" link.]

All I get is 1600 records showing the url as though everyone hasn't signed, but when I console.log has_signed in the inner loop, it's showing TRUE for the ones that should show a signatureUrl instead.

Comment: Provide more details.  What does the data model look like?  What's not right about the data after it's done.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that important information.  Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all drop all the return statements in your code. Next, use `map` instead of `forEach` as the former returns you the new manipulated array and the latter is used just for iteration purpose.

Your code within `subscribe` then becomes:

```
data.waivers = data.waivers.map((waiver) => {
    if (waiver.has_signed) { 
        // your logic goes here... 
        waiver.url = waiver.signatureUrl;
        waivers.message = "View Waiver";
    }
    // No else is required as you are just reassigning with same values
});
this.playerDetails = data;
```

At last bind this modified `data` in your template.

Comment: Thank you!  I wish I could better organize my thoughts to make these simple and clean solutions work.  It's like I can't take complicated out of things.

Comment: It's completely okay and with time it will come naturally! I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Quickly looking at it, you have a `return` statement within your `for` loop, which would stop it from running after the first iteration.

Comment: I tried it with and without return, and get the same results.  I only added it in there, thinking maybe that's why I was wrong.